# Mapbox Studio: How can I use hoover effect on layer added in Mapbox Studio style?

Tags: mapbox, shapefile, mapbox-studio

I want to make hoover effect on my map created in Mapbox Studio. I've added a SHP feature as a fill with initial opacity set in "style editor" to 0.5. How can I make hoover effect that will change that opacity to 1 when mouseon?

I've been using this example (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/) but data in this example is coming from external GEOJOSN. I want to use my layer already styled in Mapbox Studio. Is it possible? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible to achieve by referencing the name of the source which you have already added in Mapbox Studio, rather that using `Map#addSource` and `Map#addLayer` as shown in the example. That is, you can replace `'states'` in the example with the name of your source added to your map style with Mapbox Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reply. Where do I add in that case command line defining "true" and "false" values for "fill-opacity" when hover event appears?

If I don't use Map#addSource and Map#addLayer, there is no line to put new opacity values. I am really new at this so pleas understand me.

```
map.addLayer({
'id': 'state-fills',
'type': 'fill',
'source': 'states',
'layout': {},
'paint': {
'fill-color': '#627BC1',
**'fill-opacity': [
'case',
['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
1,
0.5**
]
}
});
```

and then, that case is recalled in map.on mousemove event:

```
map.on('mousemove', 'state-fills', function(e) {
if (e.features.length > 0) {
if (hoveredStateId) {
map.setFeatureState(
{ source: 'states', id: hoveredStateId },
**{ hover: false }**
);
```

If I just replace layer "states" for my layer, lets call it "PollyGon", I can't see there to define opacity values? Thank you!